# How to change video source in Amazon kinesis_video_gstreamer_sample_app.cpp?

Tags: c++, macos, gstreamer, amazon-kinesis

I am running [kinesis_video_gstreamer_sample_app.cpp](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-video-streams-producer-sdk-cpp/blob/master/kinesis-video-gst-demo/kinesis_video_gstreamer_sample_app.cpp)  on MacOS and it streams to AWS Kinesis from FaceTime (iSight) camera. How can I switch the video source to a USB Webcam? Thanks :)

Comment: I'm facing the same issue today as well. First the app correctly picked up the USB camera on the Mac. Then it somehow decided to use the built in iSight camera. Any help from anybody on how to tell the gstreamer app to use the USB camera instead of the built in iSight camera is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I figured it out finally, modify the file kinesis_video_gstreamer_sample_app.cpp as follows.

Change:

```
if (data.encoder) {
    data.source = gst_element_factory_make("autovideosrc", "source");
```

To:

```
if (data.encoder) {
    data.source = gst_element_factory_make("avfvideosrc", "source");
    g_object_set(G_OBJECT(data.source), "do-timestamp", TRUE, "device-index", 1, NULL);
```