# opencv video output to videoconferencing tools (zoom etc)

Tags: python, opencv, zoom-sdk

Been using opencv (mostly with python) for video capture/processing (Win10/Linux). Is there a way to create an output video stream that would appear as a valid source (like another camera) in videoconferencing software like zoom, skype, etc ? For now I just share the imshow() window, but it is slow/ineffective.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using OpenCV Output as Webcam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21446292/using-opencv-output-as-webcam)