# How to edit camera frames using python?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, macos-catalina

I need to edit frames of computer webcam during a live streaming (google.meet, Skype, FaceTime..).

I tried using **OpenCV**, but I don't know how to redirect the output to replace original frames of the camera or render output to the camera path.

```py
import cv2

video = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
if not video.isOpened():
    raise Exception('Video is not opened!')

while True:
    ret, frame = video.read() # Capture frame-by-frame
    
    # here edits like blur...
    blurred_frame = cv2.blur(frame, (10, 10))
    cv2.imshow('Video', blurred_frame) # Display the resulting frame

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# release the capture
video.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Someone can help me solving this problem?

I'm running on macOS Catalina, with Python 3.7.4

Comment: Your question is lacking details. How do you want to modify it exactly?

Comment: @MarkSetchell I edited the code, maybe you understand better. I need to redirect output of cv2 to webcam. Here there is an example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21446292/using-opencv-output-as-webcam but only works on Linux...

Comment: You want to send images to a camera? Normally cameras only transmit images.

Comment: I write it to you in the easiest way to understand. I need to add a filter to the images I transmit with the webcam from the computer to a live streaming system.

Comment: @M.T. "Only works for Linux"? The second answer there seems to work for both.

Comment: no It doesn't work properly

Comment: voting to close as seeking recommendations. -- recommendation: https://pypi.org/project/pyvirtualcam/ requires no workarounds involving OBS or anything

Answer (score -1):

Just display the frames in a window and use open broadcaster studio (obs) app to capture that window and use obs's virtual camera in zoom

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/pyvirtualcam/ is a better idea

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).