# Is there a way to split the video stream of an Android camera, so it can be used for two different services?

Tags: android, react-native, kotlin, ionic-framework

I need to develop an app that can make a video-call between client A and client B, while client B also send 4k video to a server to be processed with some computer vision algorithms (that need some really high quality video to perform correctly).

[connection diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F6d2M.png)

As far as I understand, and by my experience working with camera in PC, when the video is being used by a process, this resource get locked and cannot be used by another one, so I was thinking about doing something like create 2 fake cameras which I could do like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61394280/15059768) in a computer, but I'm not sure it can be done in an Android phone, specially without root permission.

Also, while I would prefer to develop in some framework that let me write code in JavaScript, like react native or ionic, I'm not constrained to a specific technology, so I'm open to the possibility to develop it in Kotlin if that gives me more control over the camera API.

Edit 1: (Trying to give more detail, as @Vidz required)

In want to send (client B) video to **just one** service that estimate some variables from the video. But at the same time, I need to use the same video (in a lower quality) for a video call between this user (B), and another type of user (client A) that doesn't send video to the server. (I was thinking about something like WebRTC for the videocall between clients).

Please see the image above for a clearer vision of the problem.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please provide more details. Do you want to send the same stream to two different services for processing?